# How can I tell if module_load_include() is working?

Tags: debugging

I'm getting errors such as

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function webform_expand_select_ids()
```

and so I'm trying to include all the includes in `/sites/all/modules/webform/components`.

I'm not even sure if that's going to help, but to help figure that out I was hoping that I could at least check and see whether `module_load_include()` is successfully including files?

```
  if ($form['#form_id'] == 'quiz_answer_key_node_form'){      
    $url = "./sites/all/modules/webform/components/*.inc";
    $filenames = glob("$url");
    $type = 'inc';
    $module = 'webform';
    foreach ($filenames as $filename)
    {
       dsm(module_load_include($type, $module, $filename));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`module_load_include()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) returns `FALSE` if it can't find the file, and the full path to the file included if it can find the file, and it was successfully included. In addition to that, it uses [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) which will throw a fatal `E_COMPILE_ERROR` error if the file is not found.

An easy way to debug would be to use code like this in your loop:

```
$file_path = module_load_include($type, $module, $filename);

if ($file_path === FALSE) {
  dpm('Failed to include: ' . $filename);
}
else {
  dpm('Successfully included: ' . $file_path);
}
```

That will give you a pretty solid answer as to whether or not the files are being included. If you get no debug messages, you know that the `glob()` isn't returning the list of files that it should be.